# Firebase Cloud Firsstore, when querying data from local cache it does not work without mobile data being on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
const cashBooksRef = firestore().collection('CashBooks');

const cashbooksQuerySnapshot = await cashBooksRef
      .where('userId', '==', userData.uid)
      .get({ source: isFromCache ? 'cache' : 'server' });
```

here, isFromCache is a variable I pass to the function, so when there is no data in cache, I am setting it to false else I am setting it to true.

First time I load data from server, then when user reopens the app I want to load from cache.
but, data from cache only shows up when my mobile data or wifi is on.
how is this offline first than?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: what is `isFromCache`? you shouldn't care that the app is offline, firebase handles that for you, no need to specify source in get.

Comment: isFromCache is variable I pass to the function, so when there is no data in cache, I am setting it to false else I am setting it to true.
but the issue is it doesn't serve data when my mobile data is off.
Do I need to setup listeners too?

Comment: you don't need to set that variable at all, you should use the default settings and not set source (firebase already does what you need by default)

Comment: I know that I was trying different options, 
finally, I was able to solve the issue by adding real time listeners